# Missing secret_key_base in Rails.application.secrets on test environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've generated simple rails api application and I've got problem with `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` - it's `nil`. I'm launching it on my local machine. 
According to [this article](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2) everything should be fine. I've got proper `app/config/credentials.yml.enc`. When I try to edit it with `rails credentials:edit` it edits properly. Actual content of it is

```
# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.
secret_key_base: 47ba27802a354b44c1cd0d0c624fcde2dced69ccfe62d274e9ecfc98d9e6671c4cf31a29aaf77af555d9553811a3ff15f22ab060e5ec5ffc0d29f77241368272
```

In all configuration files (`/app/config/environments/*.rb`) I've added `config.require_master_key = true` - it doesn't help.
My actual `Rails.application.secrets` content is `{:secret_key_base=>nil, :secret_token=>nil}`. I've dumped it in my custom class and `application_controller.rb` - this same result in both places.

Any ideas what I've missed?

PS. Before You flag this question with duplicate - note that I'm using rails 5.2 where credentials storing has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base
```

`secret_base_key` is different than `credentials` When you add the `secret_base_key` to credentials its just available as credential and not as secret.

Comment: That solves problem. I'm so blind. In article which I've linked is explicitly wrote Rails.application.credentials - not Rails.application.secrets. Shame on me. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a kind of the same problem, and at the end I found out that `rails credentials:edit` was not really saving because of the editor (I was using VS code). When I tried it with vim, it saved and everything worked as it should be. So try to set the editor to vim when you run the command as follows:

```
EDITOR=vi bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Then save with `:wq`, and try again.

Hopefully this should solve the issue :)

Comment: I've used gedit, so VSCode isn't a problem. secret_key_base is present in credentials.yml.enc and during next edits. Problem is that it is not present in Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base